# Why is the current mirrors output unequal?

Tags: current-mirror

I made a LTspice simulation of a pmos current mirror. The current source should model a photodiode (without parasitic capacity). The W/L ratio is the same for both Mosfets. I expected the plot of the output current (red) to be the same as the input current (blue). I thought it will rise in a linear manner as the input current (the sweep is linear).
Now I see that the output current is logarithmic (see plot: red curve).
Can someone explain this difference?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Channel length modulation may be the answer

Comment: What's your load resistance? I see a voltage source in series with two current sources. This ain't gonna work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your power supply is only 1 volt so you are operating the mosfets in the linear part of their characteristic. Try increasing the supply to about 10 volts.

Comment: I agree with this answer, because channel length modulation is less pronounced in PMOSFETS.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain this difference?

what happens if you increase V1 to like 10v?

Answer (score 0):

Even with higher voltages across the "current mirror", one FET is diode-connected and will not experience the full voltage, while the other FET always has full voltage across Drain_Source.